# Least eccentricity vertex can't have the most average distance

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle

The eccentricity of a vertex $\epsilon (v) $ is the maximum of distances $d(v, u) $ over all other vertices $u$. The average distance of a vertex  avgd$(v) $ is the average of all $d(v, u)$, more precisely $avgd(v) =\frac{\sum_{u\neq v} d(v, u)} {|V|-1}$

Now if the center of a graph is one single vertex $v$, that is, there is a least eccentric vertex $v$ , so $\epsilon (v) <\epsilon (u), u \neq v$, then avgd$(v) < \max(avgd(u)_{u \in V}) $  because this  vertex $v$ can't  simultaneously have  the greatest average distance.

At least, that's what I assume. My intuition comes from a Graph where a small clique and a big clique are connected with one separate vertex. That vertex is then the least eccentric, but the small clique vertices have always a higher average distance. Anyone a proof or a counterexample?

Some of my thoughts about this conjecture :

I now realize that a graph consisting of one single vertex would be a trivial counterexample, so let's only consider simple connected  graphs with more than one vertex.

I generated many graphs with a single vertex center and could indeed always find an  $u$ with strictly greater average distance than the center. I wondered if we can also find such $u$ that is adjacent to the center, but that's not always the case.

Although it might sound intuitive or  trivial that the most central point is not the point with the greatest average distance, it's not generally the case for any metric. It's  not generally true for the Euclidean distance for example.

I thought it might be true because if there is singular center $ v$, then some $v*$ has a shortest path through the center for more than half of the other vertices. But this turned out to be false, I found graphs with a singular center but without such a $v*$

Comment: Interesting question!

Comment: Is it troublesome for you to include a graph that shows a counterexample for the Euclidean distance? A graph is always attractive.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Consider a pyramid whose base is a $6 \times 8$ rectangle, and the distance from the rectangle’s vertices to the pyramid’s apex point is $9$. The average distance and the eccentricity of the apex are both $9$. The eccentricity of the other four vertices is $\sqrt{6^2+8^2}=10$, but their average distance is just $(6+8+\sqrt{6^2+8^2}+9)/4 = 8.25$. So, the apex is the least eccentric point and also the point with the largest average distance.

Comment: @Apass.Jack a map where there are two clusters/hubs  of points, plus one more point v* forming a triangle with the two clusters, so that v* is the center.

Comment: I'm on my phone but I'll upload a visual counterexample of the euclidiana. I also found counterexamples in the sense that the most averagely distant point is in fact in the center of the graph, if we don't restrict the center to be a singular vertex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Counterexample.** Take $6$ disjoint $2$-element vertex sets $V_i=\{x_i,y_i\}$ ($0\le i\le5$); draw $30$ edges making $V_i\cup V_j$ a clique for $i-j\equiv1\pmod6$; add a $13^\text{th}$ vertex $z$ and edges $y_0z$ and $y_3z$. You can easily verify that in this graph
$$\epsilon(z)=2;$$
$$\epsilon(x_i)=\epsilon(y_i)=3;$$
$$\operatorname{avgd}(z)=\frac{22}{12};$$
$$\operatorname{avgd}(y_0)=\operatorname{avgd}(y_3)=\frac{19}{12};$$
and for vertices $v\notin\{z,y_0,y_3\}$,
$$\operatorname{avgd}(v)=\frac{21}{12}.$$
**Generalizing this construction,** for integers $k\ge1$ and $n\ge2$ there is a graph of order $(4k+2)n+1$, radius $2$ and diameter $3$, with a unique vertex $z$ of eccentricity $2$ which has average distance
$$\operatorname{avgd}(z)=\frac{2(4k+2)n-2}{(4k+2)n}=2-\frac1{(2k+1)n}$$
while
$$\max_{v\ne z}\operatorname{avgd}(v)=\frac{(6k+4)n+1}{(4k+2)n}=\frac32+\frac{1+\frac1n}{4k+2}.$$
For this take $(4k+2)n$ vertices, divided into $4k+2$ "blobs" of $n$ vertices each; arrange the blobs in a circle; join each vertex to all other vertices in its own blob and the $k$ nearest blobs on either side; finally add a central vertex $z$ and join it to two vertices which are in diametrically opposite blobs.